# Fill the table value in combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Using VS2005 with C#

I want to fill the combobox by using the table value.

Code

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
    OdbcCommand cmd;

con.ConnectionString =                            "";
        con.Open();
        cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select no from table", con);
        ada = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ada.Fill(ds);
        combobox1.Items.Add(ds);
```

But no values was loading in the combobox, what wrong with my above mentioned code.

can any provide a solution for the probelm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do** have something in your real connection string, right?

You're loading your data into a **DataSet** - that's a collection of tables and relations. How should the combobox know what table's data to display?? If the `DataSet` has multiple tables in it, you would have to additionally define which one of those to use. If the `DataSet` has only one table inside, then it's a waste of resources to use a `DataSet` in the first place.

If you only have a single set of data, use a `DataTable` instead:

```
con.Open();
cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select no from table", con);
ada = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable data = new DataTable();
ada.Fill(data);

// define the column to be used to display text in the combobox
combobox1.DataTextField = "FirstName";
// define the column to be used as the value for the selection in the combobox
combobox1.DataValueField = "CustomerID";

combobox1.DataSource = data;
combobox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: In a combobox showing System.Data.Datarowview instead of value

Comment: @marc there is datatextfield n datavaluefield in combobox